# MacOS X change keyboard layout when using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-layout

I use the international english keyboard and the standard english keyboard when i'm programming. Is there a way for me to switch off the international keyboard only on the terminal automatically?

Comment: What do you consider to be "Standard English"? That definition is going to be highly contended by residents either side of the Atlantic ;)

Comment: In terms of the keyboard no modifications. I think that would be standard for anyone using an english keyboard.

Comment: Nope. 'standard' can be ANSI or ISO, at minimum. Anyway, wish you luck.

Answer (score 1):

If it is input sources you're talking about, menu bar has a shortcut if it's enabled in Keyboard preferences. And ctrl + Space also works to switch languages.

For automation, you need to show some understanding of AppleScript.